# Как правильно тестировать fastify приложение с supertest?

Tags: node.js, юнит-тесты, fastify

Пытаюсь прикрутить supertest к fastify:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('fastify')();

app.get('/user', function(_, res) {
   res.status(200).send({ name: 'john' });
});

request(app.server)
   .get('/user')
   .then(res => {
      console.info(res.body);
   });
```

В консоли вижу:

```
{ statusCode: 404, error: 'Not Found', message: 'Not Found' }
```

ЧЯДНТ? Как получить ответ от приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации fastify описаны несколько подходов к тестированию приложений, твой подход ближе всего к [Testing with a running server](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Testing/#testing-with-a-running-server)

Причина твоего кейса в том, что у тебя не запускается сам сервер:

> await app.ready()

```
Promise { <pending> } // в эксперименте я не стал ждать resolve этого promise

{"level":30,"time":1603197725330,"pid":45535,"hostname":"negroponta-mac.local","reqId":1,"req":{"method":"GET","url":"/user","hostname":"127.0.0.1:62962","remoteAddress":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","remotePort":62963},"msg":"incoming request"}
{"level":30,"time":1603197725338,"pid":45535,"hostname":"negroponta-mac.local","reqId":1,"res":{"statusCode":200},"responseTime":6.021948993206024,"msg":"request completed"}
{ name: 'john' }
```

---

Полный пример:

```
const tap = require('tap')
const supertest = require('supertest')

tap.test('GET `/user` route', async (t) => {
  const app = require('fastify')();
  app.get('/user', function(_, res) {
    res.status(200).send({ name: 'john' });
  });

  t.tearDown(() => app.close())

  await app.ready()

  const response = await supertest(app.server)
    .get('/user')
    .expect(200)
    .expect('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
  t.deepEqual(response.body, { name: 'john' })
})
```

Comment: интересно, спасибо. попробую ближайшее время

Comment: @muturgan ок. я поправил "полный" листинг, чтобы он был ближе к твоему вопросу